# pipe the output of sys.stdout to text browser in pyqt

Tags: pyqt, qtextbrowser

I m trying to pipe my output to text browser of pyqt. right now i m creating a class having only write method.

```
class port:
    def __init__(self,view):
        self.view = view

    def write(self,*args):
        self.view.append(*args)
```

then just

```
text_browser = QTextBrowser()
sys.stdout = port(text_browser)
```

this works fine but is there a better way ? and also for the `AttributeError: 'port' object has no attribute 'flush'`i have to create a flush method which does nothing , so could there be a cleaner way?

Comment: qt does have file-like streams (which can trigger events), but if this works, why change?

Comment: Could u elaborate on that  ,havent used qt much so dont know about that

Comment: Sounds like you don't need to, but documentation is here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html