# How to redirect Python script output to PyQT5 GUI Console, without any buttons clicks?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, stdout, stderr, qtextbrowser

Hey I am using the same old code for getting all the code outputs PyQT5 QTexBrowser GUI console, but I am also getting next line character ("\n") in all new lines.

Code URL - [pipe the output of sys.stdout to text browser in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326493/pipe-the-output-of-sys-stdout-to-text-browser-in-pyqt/63110323#63110323)

Below is the code I am using from above URL -

```
class Port(object):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def write(self, *args):
        # self.view.append(str([*args]))
        # self.view.append(str(*args).rstrip("\n").lstrip("\n"))
        self.view.append(*args)
```

GUI Console Output -
[image]

Is there any way to remove `"\n"` from the args, Please suggest.

when I used below line, then I was able to see that there is `"\n"` in every new args.

```
self.view.append(str([*args]))
```

GUI Console Output with visible `"\n"` (* Ignore the numbers in lines as first character - that is part of user selection output.)
[image]

then I tried to do every possible way to remove like strip(), lstrip() etc, still didn't get success.

Below is the part of code, how I am redirecting run time output to `QtextBrowser`

```
        self.execution_result = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.execution_result.setObjectName("execution_result")

        self.execution_rslt_saveresult_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.execution_result)
        self.execution_rslt_saveresult_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1220, 780, 131, 25))
        self.execution_rslt_saveresult_btn.setObjectName("execution_rslt_saveresult_btn")
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                   Console Output
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.execution_result)
        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(2, 1, 1371, 771))
        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser.setObjectName("execution_rslt_textbrowser")

        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser.setStyleSheet(
            """QTextBrowser {background-color:  #000000;
                               color: #00FF00;
                               font: 11pt Courier new;}""")
        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser.document().setPlainText(
            "-" * 40 + '\n' + "     Log starts from below line   " + '\n' + "-" * 40)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Below line is sending run time output to GUI console
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
        sys.stdout = Port(self.execution_rslt_textbrowser)
```

Please anyone suggest what should I do here to remove `"\n"` from the outputlines.
also how to remove error `AttributeError: 'port' object has no attribute 'flush'`

***Below is the working sample code with next line character issue. - For reference/debugging***

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Port(object):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def write(self, *args):
        # self.view.append(str([*args])) # This line will highlight next line character in console "\n"
        self.view.append(*args)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        # MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 500)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 500))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 500))
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 500))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 883))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 0, 671, 341))
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")


        self.execution_result = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.execution_result.setObjectName("execution_result")
        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.execution_result)
        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, 1, 681, 321))
        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser.setObjectName("execution_rslt_textbrowser")
        self.execution_rslt_textbrowser.document().setPlainText(
            "-" * 40 + '\n' + "     Log starts from below line   " + '\n' + "-" * 40)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#               Console Output Redirection
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
        sys.stdout = Port(self.execution_rslt_textbrowser)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------#


        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.execution_result, "")
        self.mainwindow_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainwindow_list.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 241, 301))
        self.mainwindow_list.setObjectName("mainwindow_list")

        self.mainwindow_list.itemClicked['QListWidgetItem*'].connect(self.qlistoptions)

        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.mainwindow_list.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.mainwindow_list.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.mainwindow_list.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.mainwindow_list.addItem(item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.execution_result), _translate("MainWindow", "Execution Console"))

        __sortingEnabled = self.mainwindow_list.isSortingEnabled()
        self.mainwindow_list.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.mainwindow_list.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item1"))
        item = self.mainwindow_list.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item2"))
        item = self.mainwindow_list.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item3"))
        item = self.mainwindow_list.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item4"))
        self.mainwindow_list.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


    def qlistoptions(self):
        print("Inside qlistoptions method : Button Clicked")
        # window.hide()  ## This to close main window and open new window.
        print(self.mainwindow_list.currentRow())  # Will Return Index number of list item
        print(self.mainwindow_list.currentItem().text())  # Will Return current selected text from list item
        # print("Signal-", self.mainwindow_ok.isChecked())

        # Item1
        if self.mainwindow_list.currentRow() == 0:
            print("Item1 is Clicked!!")
        # Item2
        elif self.mainwindow_list.currentRow() == 1:
            print("Item2 is Clicked!!")
        # Item3
        elif self.mainwindow_list.currentRow() == 2:
            print("Item3 is Clicked!!")
        # Item4
        elif self.mainwindow_list.currentRow() == 3:
            print("Item4 is Clicked!!")
        else:
            print("Please select any item first!!")

    def printText(self, button):
        print("Value from printText Method -")
        print(button.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc sample reproducible code has been added for reference. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The append method adds an additional endline, the solution is to insert the text without adding it:

```
class Port(object):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def write(self, text):
        cursor = self.view.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(text)
        self.view.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.view.ensureCursorVisible()
```

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc  Awesome!!! it solved the issue.. Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I write with command: `sys.stdout.write("Append a line to console!")`, it's all good, nothing redundant.

To delete the flush attribute error, just add to your Port class this override function:

```
def flush(self):
    pass
```

Tested!

Comment: Many Thanks... `def flush(self)` removed the error `AttributeError: 'port' object has no attribute 'flush'` But new line issue is still there.... I am using `sys.stdout = Port(self.execution_rslt_textbrowser)` for calling  method  `def write(self, *args):` and there `self.view.append(str([*args]))` line is adding the data to console but with `\n` ....  By `sys.stdout.write("Append a line to console!")` I can print the data onto console but I need all arguments generated by my code. :( , let me know if there is any other suggestions.